# Regex: How to replace a symbol between Non-English String but not English one

Tags: php, regex

I have a string where it contains English and Non-English characters, and both of them contains the `underscore symbol _` between them.

I would like to remove the underscore from the Non-English string only and leave the underscore that is between the english characters only.

**Example: Hello_this is me , مرحبا_اناهنا**

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What about underscores that have a space or an end of the string next to them? Or digits? Or will there always be either two ASCII or two non-ASCII characters next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This preg_replace might work:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[^\x00-\x80])_(?=[^\x00-\x80])/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Didn't work. Any way you could work around this? /[_\W]*/ I'm trying to remove everything except the english and the underscore between its letters. `ex: Hello_this is me` , مرحبا_اناهنا `will result: hello_this is me`

Comment: Thanks, I think I miscopied it! How can you remove all the Non-English Letters along with their underscore?

Comment: Didn't understand your comment clearly. You just want to remove underscore between non-english alphabets right?

Comment: Yes but an additional question, if I want to remove Non-English letters too, how will it be?

Comment: If you want to remove all non-english letters then use: `preg_replace('/[^\x00-\x80]+/', '', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\p{Arabic})_(?=\p{Arabic})/', '', $s)
```

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<pre><?php

$subject = "Hello_this is me , مرحبا_اناهنا";

$pattern = '~\p{Arabic}\K_(?=\p{Arabic})~u';

echo $subject . '<br/>' . preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $subject);
```

Note that i use the u modifier to treat unicode strings.

The `\K` reset the match before it, but you can replace this trick by a lookbehind as anubhava and ctn suggests it.

Comment: Will try it as soon as I get back. Thanks